# Is there not a 'Trinitarian' tag?

Tags: support

I attempted to put in a 'Trinitarian' tag and there appeared to be both 'trinitarian' and a 'non-trinitarian' tags but when I chose the 'trinitarian' it did not come up in to the tag box.

Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: It's a duplicate of the "trinity" tag.

Comment: See https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7030/there-are-too-many-trinity-tags-and-not-enough-too/7031#7031

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't tag a question like this [Do Trinitarian Protestants regard it as wrong to make false claims publicly?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/85810/do-trinitarian-protestants-regard-it-as-wrong-to-make-false-claims-publicly) with [trinitarian](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trinitarian) it's not about trinitarianism, it's about asking about Protestants.  I preferred the old method of writing "when I say Protestants... I mean ..."  or something like that.

Mormons and Jehovahs witnesses don't consider themselves Protestants, and neither do Evangelicals (I've heard) but you *are* asking Evangelicals whereas you're not asking Unitarians.

But to reiterate, please don't use the [trinity](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trinity) to do anything except ask questions revolving around the Trinity.  It's hard to see how an orthodox understanding of the Trinity would impact that question's answer. Tagging is for sorting and categorization,  not for scoping; the title and the content of the question are great (and sufficient).

Comment: "neither do Evangelicals (I've heard)" No, evangelicals should almost without exception consider themselves Protestants.

Comment: But your point is good here. Even if there was a distinct "trinitarian" tag that wasn't a synonym of the "trinity" tag, it wouldn't be a good site scope because it's just too broad - except for questions asking directly about the Trinity.

Comment: @curiousdannii technically you're right, Evangelicals should consider themselves Protestants, I wonder if we've had that question yet.  I'd imagine "Are Evangelicals Protestants" has a different answer than "Do Evangelicals consider themselves Protestants"  at least in the USA.

Comment: Well the political sense of "evangelical" shouldn't even really be on-topic here. For the theological sense, I can't imagine there'd be any evangelicals who don't consider themselves protestant, unless they're ignorant of what the labels mean.

Comment: Many Biblical Unitarians consider themselves Protestants. Other Protestants tend to disagree. There's an important conceptual distinction between Protestant and Trinitarian Protestant.