# Should we separate out a 'Trinitarian' tag?

Tags: discussion

Right now, 'Trinity' and 'Trinitarian' are [duplicate tags](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7128/is-there-not-a-trinitarian-tag).

This doesn't seem right to me. I might want to ask a question about the Trinity from a Trinitarian POV, a Binitarian POV, or a Unitarian POV. The Trinity and Trinitarianism are importantly different conceptually.

Should we separate out the tags 'Trinity' and 'Trinitarian'?

Answer (score 5):

> I might want to ask a question about the Trinity from a Trinitarian POV, a Binitarian POV, or a Unitarian POV. The Trinity and Trinitarianism are importantly different conceptually.

Well yes. But in the same way we don't have separate Catholic-Church-as-a-topic and Catholicism-as-a-viewpoint tags. No one seems to have minded tagging questions about Catholicism from a Protestant viewpoint and questions about Protestantism from a Catholic viewpoint with equivalent tags. The questions make clear what the subject matter and viewpoints are.

IMO, in general we don't need separate topic and viewpoint tags. Maybe there are specific cases where it would be more helpful, but I'm not persuaded yet that Trinity/Trinitarianism is one of them.

Comment: "The question makes clear what the subject matter and viewpoints are." Sure, but the whole point of tags is so you don't have to sift through irrelevant questions, no?

Comment: I'm not 100% opposed to the idea of separating the tags, but if we did it for the Trinity/Trinitarianism, shouldn't we do it for everything else too? What would we call all the tags? *-viewpoint?

Comment: This is a downstream issue of deciding most things should be scoped to a POV. Once you have that, the POV and the subject become importantly different. But in this particular case, we have a bit of a strange asymmetry, because I can tag 'unitarianism', 'non-trinitarian', but I can't tag explicitly 'trinitarian', only 'trinity'.

Comment: That's mostly a historical accident. We could swap which was the main tag and which is the duplicate.

Comment: Ya, maybe bring 'trinitarian', 'binitarian', 'unitarian', and 'non-trinitarian' into line.

Answer (score -3):

I am of the mind that we should entirely ban the topic (and the anti-topic) as opinion based unless specifically asking for a doctrinal (pertaining to a particular denomination), traditional (pertaining to a particular extra-biblical thing handed on), historical (pertaining to a specific event in Christian history; a council or something) or critical (pertaining to a specific work on the Subject) answer to the question.

My suggestion would be to *not* allow [trinitarian](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trinitarian) unless accompanied by something else that would make it topical (same as nearly any other topic).  And the same for [non-trinitarian](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/non-trinitarian).  Except for [unitarian](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unitarian), which is more or less a denomination, all *nitarian questions would be off topic.

How we can draw a specific distinction about the Trinity, but not the Eucharist (which are the same thing in my personal opinion) and the understand of the Eucharist as the Body, Blood, Soul and Divinity is older and clearer and more Scriptural than the Trinity is beyond my comprehension.

Nothing would please me more than closing all of these questions, even if they're mine.

---

Also, you're misinterpreting what the tags are for.  They're for classifications, not viewpoints.  Tagging a question is separate from scoping a question.  Therefore [trinitarian](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trinitarian) doesn't make sense on the site other than as a synonym for [trinity](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trinity) or [trinitarianism](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trinitarianism).

The subject of the question is the matter for the tag, not the audience. Please flag any inconsistencies!

Comment: "we should entirely ban" This would really zap discussion of contemporary thinkers or theologians.

Comment: "They're for classifications, not viewpoints" I understand this Peter. As pointed out above, 'Trinity' and 'Trinitarianism' are conceptually distinct.

Comment: You've been saying this a lot recently, but I'm yet to see you actually identify any problematic questions. Or at least any that have caused problems beyond your dislike of them. :)

Comment: @PeterTurner Given the question was migrated, why the comment "You're gonna have to try harder than that to frame a question for this site."? And why the sudden closing with no warning?

Comment: @PeterTurner https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/93837/according-to-those-who-believe-philippians-26-says-jesus-is-god-why-did-paul-a

Comment: @One I didn't notice that, honestly in 5 years of moderating the site, that's the first one I sent back.

Comment: @curious every question asked across denominations and interpretation needs a microscope and I make no apologies for judging peoples intentions when they get people riled up and we have to send all the comments to chatrooms.   We either need to be more stringent on the questions or the criteria for what makes a supported answer.  We are talking about absolute Truth Itself when discussing the Trinity which is why we need to take it seriously.  These people are asking questions from left field as if they were normal things that come up in conversation or worse, good points.

Comment: Sorry to appear so dogmatic about it, but when I see a question about the Catholic Church I expect a Catholic answer.  When I see a question about the Trinity, likewise, I expect a Catholic answer and then I remember that the Trinity is a common doctrine.  It does not stand to reason that those who abandoned two fundamental deposits of faith would come to the same conclusions as those with all three.  Therefore you cannot ask a question about the Trinity - or any other doctrine - without sufficient scoping.  It's like accepting Lutheran answers on questions on the Eucharist.

Comment: "we have to send all the comments to chatrooms" Why is this such a big deal? Don't mods have tools to make sending comments to a chatroom easy?

Comment: @one moderators are exception handlers. If you're programming something and you encounter too many exceptions, you need to root out the defects.  One of the defects in our system is that we allow Q's asked about the Trinity and not [Chalcedonic Christianity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chalcedonian_Christianity) specifically.

Comment: Perhaps obviously, I don't think it's a defect. These questions are interesting, evidently, to a significant number of people. C SE is for asking and answering useful or important questions re Christianity, and almost no one even has heard of 'Chalcedonic Christianity'. If comments are a side-effect of that, I think the appropriate thing to do is teach commenters how to make chat rooms so they don't clutter it up (honestly, give some guff to the SE peeps so they make doing this easier), and have a policy for repeat offenders to nip it in the bud.

Comment: If you really think no one has heard of Chalcedonic Christianity why are you asking questions about Trinitarianism?  All you're doing is collecting opinions, that's the defect.  It's no surprise that people like to argue over your questions.

Comment: Huh? I'm not sure what difference 'Trinitarian' vs. 'Chalcedonian Trinitarian' would make for most questions asked re Trinitarianism on the site. Trinitarian = Chalcedonian for most purposes. They're not arguing because I didn't distinguish Chalcedonian vs. Semi-Ch vs. Non-Ch. They're arguing because they feel strongly about their Trinitarian (Chalcedonian or not!) or Unitarian values.

Comment: Hold on, you think most people have heard of or know what Chalcedonic Christianity is? They could give a decent definition off-hand? Virtually no one can do this. C SE isn't supposed to be a repository for academia, it's for the vast number of Christians who want to quickly find answers to questions they have. btw those terrible comments that are such a pain for your royal mod butts? They often contain more interesting info than the answers themselves.

Comment: @one Modalists are Trinitarians, but when you're asking "Trinitarians" you're not intending to ask modalists, right?

Comment: @PeterTurner How many modalists do you know?

Comment: Are Modalists even Trinitarians, tho'? I don't think so ...

Comment: @one it depends on what you mean by Trinitarian.  They're clearly more Trinitarian than _you_ which means it's not cut and dry as you'd hope when you ask questions about the Trinity.

Comment: I think you perhaps should ask a new question whether according to Trinitarians Modalists are Trinitarians. ;) Watch the sparks fly!

Comment: I consider Biblical Unitarians closer to Trinitarians than Modalists. It's because Trinitarians recognize more distinction between the Father and Jesus, although it's a bit vague and there are variations of Modalism. Uh oh, can't scope to Modalism now because it's vague!

Comment: But I think it's pretty clear Modalism isn't a form of Trinitarianism. Trinitarians historically considered Modalism a heresy. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modalistic_Monarchianism

Comment: The point is, modalism is a Trinitarian heresy that was rejected by Church Councils (like Chalcedon).  But when you ask about The Trinity, it's impossible to know if you're not asking about Trinitarian Heresies (Unitarianism is a rejection of the Trinity, not a contrary understanding of the doctrine).   Since we don't discriminate on this site and it _is_ an academic site, I really need you to be more specific who you're asking so I can moderate answers better.

Comment: "Unitarianism is a rejection of the Trinity" Well, Unitarianism understood as, say, Dynamic Monarchianism (close to contemporary BU) pre-dated Trinitarianism. But sure, the label 'Unitarian' is a reaction to the development of Trinitarianism.

Comment: OK - that's fine, but Unitarianism doesn't resemble Trinitarianism in the same way that modalism does.  It doesn't show up on [St. Patrick Bad Analogies](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KQLfgaUoQCw)

Comment: "I really need you to be more specific who you're asking so I can moderate answers better." OK, next time I'll specify I want the Shwarzenau Brethren Anabaptist POV. ;)

Comment: @Peter Modalists are definitely not Trinitarian, but if you thought they were it would make sense why you'd be thinking Trinitarian questions were so problematic.

Comment: Questions should be scoped to the subject matter. Questions can be both too broad and too narrowly scoped. Questions about the Trinity should generally not be scoped to a particular Trinitarian denomination, but instead to the whole of Nicene Christianity. The authoritative reference for Trinitarianism is the ecumenical creeds. The theology of Trinitarianism is shared by all the Trinitarian denominations, but they have different ways of explaining that theology. That's why we can have different answers to Trinitarian questions, but they're not competing on theology, just how they explain it.

Comment: @curiousdannii then why don't we flag and delete all the answers that fail to reference conciliar documents?

Comment: @PeterTurner I explained my thinking in more detail here: https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7382/6071

Comment: @PeterTurner "We are talking about absolute Truth Itself when discussing the Trinity".  While I personally agree with you my understanding is that, here on Christianit-SE, this same statement is not welcome.  There are plenty of "Christians" who use this site and who do not believe that the Trinity is absolute truth.

Comment: @mike yes, that is why we need to ban the questions.  The only reason I participate is so that I can talk about absolute truth and ignore (other than for purposes of moderation) the questions who I fundamentally do not agree with.  The problem is we technically allow questions directed 'at Trinitarians' that aren't about the Trinity (as far as I can tell, most of them are about the Hypostatic Union).  Do we also allow questions aimed 'at Trinitarians' that are also about the Eucharist?  I hope not!